# php correct json manifest

Tags: php, manifest.json, lighthouse

I have errors on png image, Do you know how to resolve this problem ?

Thank you.

> Web app manifest does not meet the installability
>   requirementsFailures: Manifest does not have a PNG icon of at least
>   192px.
>
> Is not configured for a custom splash screenFailures: Manifest does
>   not have a PNG icon of at least 512px. A themed splash screen ensures
>   a high-quality experience when users launch your app from their
>   homescreens. Learn more.

my php json about the manifest

```
$manifest = [
    "dir" => "ltr",
    "lang" => "{$code_langue}",
    "name" => "{$siteName}",
    "short_name" => "{$shortName}",
    "description" => "{$description}",
    "scope" => "{$scope}",
    "display" => "standalone",
    "start_url" => "{$scope}",
    "theme_color" => "#317EFB",
    "orientation" => "any",
    "background_color" => "#fff",
    "related_applications" => "",
    "prefer_related_applications" => "false",
    "screenshots" => [],
    "generated" => "true",
    "icons" => [
      "src" => "{$image_512}",
      "sizes"=> "192x192 512x512",
      "type" => "image/png"
    ],
    "src" => "{$image_512}",
    "sizes" => "512x512",
    "type" => "image/png"
  ];

   $json_manifest = json_encode($manifest);
```